# Why does Type II/III ANOVA on cumulative link model (R-package ordinal) give different results depending on factor order?

Tags: r, anova, ordinal-data, ordered-probit

From what I understand, type II and type III ANOVA should give the same result irrespective of the order of the factors in the formula because they calculate:

```
Type II: 
    SS(A | B) for factor A. 
    SS(B | A) for factor B. 
    SS(A:B|A,B) for the interaction. 
Type III:
    SS(A | B, A:B) for factor A. 
    SS(B | A, A:B) for factor B. 
    SS(A:B|A,B) for the interaction.
```

But when I run `clm` from the `ordinal` R-package on my data and then perform type II (or type III) ANOVA using the `Anova` function from the `car` R-package, I obtain completely different results depending on the order of my factors.

**Edit 2:**
After a little bit of trial and error, I managed to make better example data for my issue:

```
dat<-data.frame(Treatment=c("Control","TreatmentA","TreatmentB","Control","TreatmentA","TreatmentB"),
Judge=c("C","C","C","E","E","E"),
VeryLow=c(2,3,2,2,3,2),
Low=c(1,3,6,1,3,6),
High=c(3,3,5,3,3,5),
VeryHigh=c(68,76,72,68,76,72))

# Some code to make the count data compatible with the clm package
orderedLevels<-c("VeryLow","Low","High","VeryHigh")
longDat<-reshape(dat, varying=orderedLevels, v.names="rating_count",timevar="rating",times=orderedLevels,direction="long")
indivDat<-longDat[rep(seq(1, nrow(longDat)), longDat$rating_count),]
indivDat$rating<-ordered(indivDat$rating, levels=orderedLevels)
summary(indivDat)

# The clm models without interactions
library(ordinal);library(car)
fm1 <- clm(rating ~ Treatment + Judge, data=indivDat)
fm2 <- clm(rating ~ Judge + Treatment, data=indivDat)
Anova(fm1, type="II"); Anova(fm2, type="II")

# The lm equivalent models without interactions
indivDat$rating_num<- as.numeric(indivDat$rating)
fm3 <- lm(rating_num ~ Treatment + Judge, data=indivDat)
fm4 <- lm(rating_num ~ Judge + Treatment, data=indivDat)
Anova(fm3, type="II"); Anova(fm4, type="II")
```

The results for this new example are:

```
> Anova(fm1, type="II")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: rating
          Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
Treatment  2 92.725    < 2e-16 ***
Judge      1 53.275    2.9e-13 ***
---

> Anova(fm2, type="II")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: rating
          Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
Judge      1 92.426  < 2.2e-16 ***
Treatment  2 76.882  < 2.2e-16 ***
---

> Anova(fm3, type="II")
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: rating_num
           Sum Sq  Df F value Pr(>F)
Treatment   1.177   2  1.3917 0.2497
Judge       0.000   1  0.0000 1.0000
Residuals 204.659 484   

> Anova(fm4, type="II")
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: rating_num
           Sum Sq  Df F value Pr(>F)
Judge       0.000   1  0.0000 1.0000
Treatment   1.177   2  1.3917 0.2497
Residuals 204.659 484
```

How can the Judge effect be significant with the clm package when the data for each judge is just a copy of each other? And why does the order of the factor in the cum link model matters?

What is going on here? Did I misunderstood the type II/III Anova? And what is the best course of action when analyzing such a data set?

**Original example (without results):**
Here is a reproducible example for Type II using the `wine` dataset:

```
library(ordinal)
fm1 <- clm(rating ~ contact * bottle, data=wine)
fm2 <- clm(rating ~ bottle * contact, data=wine)

library(car)
Anova(fm1, type="II"); Anova(fm2, type="II")
```

**Edit 1:** Same model without interactions.

```
> fm1 <- clm(rating ~ contact + bottle, data=wine)
> Anova(fm1, type="II")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: rating
        Df   Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
contact  1  1.8182     0.1775    
bottle   7 53.1100  3.526e-09 ***

> fm2 <- clm(rating ~ bottle + contact, data=wine)
> Anova(fm2, type="II")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: rating
        Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
bottle   7 71.534  7.231e-13 ***
contact  1  6.847   0.008879 **
```

Comment: You've got a problem with your data. The df for the interaction should be 7. Given that it is 3 indicates that you have cells with no data.

Comment: `wine` is the example data from the `ordinal` package. It does not contain any missing data. @dbwilson You are right that the interaction doesn't make sense here because bottles 1,2,5 and 6 always have "no" contact and the rest of the bottles (3,4,7 and 8) always have a "yes" for contact. But (1) removing the interaction term does not solve the problem. (2) Shouldn't Anova type II and III results be independent of the order of the factor even if the data is unbalanced?

Comment: That is the problem. Contact is fully determined by bottle. As such, this data is not appropriate for a two-way ANOVA. With data in all 16 cells (8 bottles, 2 contacts) then the order of the factors would not matter. Also note that this is not a standard ANOVA model (I didn't notice this initially) given that the DV is coded as ordinal and not scaled (hence the analysis of deviance with a chisq rather than analysis of variance with an F). I'm not sure how the latter would be affected by the Type II/III distinction.

Comment: @dbwilson (1) If the data was perfectly balanced, not only would both order give the same results but ANOVA type I, II and III would also give the same results. So that would completely defeat the purpose of this question. Of course this is an extreme example, but I get the same with less unbalanced data. (2) Indeed, I only get this issue with `clm` models for `ordinal` response. But shouldn't the Chi-square test be symmetrical just like the F-test? Otherwise, what does Type II and III mean in for this test?

Comment: Having data in each cell of the design is not the same thing as a balanced design. The latter is the same sample size in each cell. You are correct that with a truly balanced design, Type I, II, and III SS give the same results. That said, it appears that you've identified the issue as the clm model. I don't have any experience with these so can't answer why the chi-square test in this situation would be different, but clearly it is.

Comment: In your example, bottles are nested within contacts. Correcting what I said above, you can do a two-way anova but the interaction between these two doesn't make sense: it is not possible for the effect of bottle to differ between contacts=0 and contacts=1.

Comment: @dbwilson Indeed, empty cells and unbalanced is not the same. I answered a bit to hastily, sorry. But I had difficulties making a small reproducible example that made sense. In any case, I observe the same issue without interactions and without empty cells in my data. I think there is an issue with the way ANOVA is performed on `clm` objects because if I have the exact same data for the 2 levels of a factor, the factor still appears significant! And if I do the Chi-square test by dropping or adding terms manually the results look much more consistent!

Comment: @dbwilson explained what the problem is with that particular data.  For an example without issue, try the following. `library(ordinal); library(car); fm1 <- clm(rating ~ contact * temp, data=wine); fm2 <- clm(rating ~ temp * contact, data=wine); Anova(fm1, type="II"); Anova(fm2, type="II")`

Comment: Also note that you get useless results if you use lm rather than clm for the contact / bottle data.  `library(car); wine$rating.num = as.numeric(wine$rating); fm3 <- lm(rating.num ~ contact * bottle, data=wine); fm4 <- lm(rating.num ~ bottle * contact, data=wine); Anova(fm3, type="II"); Anova(fm4, type="II")`

Comment: I made a new example data set to show that even on a data set with all possible combinations of parameters, ANOVA on clm can have a similar unexpected behavior.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Indeed, I get useless results with the `lm` too but at least the absence of results and 0 Df for the interaction term shows clearly where the issue lies in that case! Similarly, in the new example data set, the `lm` Anova results are consistent with the data and independent of the term order whereas the `clm` Anova results are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/2.1-5/topics/Anova) for `car::Anova` does not indicate that it works with clm or clmm objects. From your examples, it appears it can have some unusual behavior.

[My solution](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_11.html) is to use [RVAideMemoire::Anova.clm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RVAideMemoire/versions/0.9-35/topics/Anova.clm).

So, for your EDIT 2 example:

```
if(!require(RVAideMemoire)){install.packages("RVAideMemoire")}
if(!require(car)){install.packages("car")}

library(car)

library(RVAideMemoire)

Anova(fm1, type="II")

### Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

### Response: rating
###           LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
### Treatment   4.0507  2     0.1319
### Judge       0.0000  1     1.0000

Anova(fm2, type="II")

### Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

### Response: rating
###           LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
### Judge       0.0000  1     1.0000
### Treatment   4.0507  2     0.1319
```

Note that this produces the same p-values as the `anova` function.

```
fm1 <- clm(rating ~ Treatment + Judge, data=indivDat)
fmx <- clm(rating ~ Treatment, data=indivDat)
fmy <- clm(rating ~ Judge, data=indivDat)

anova(fm1, fmx)

### Likelihood ratio tests of cumulative link models:

###     formula:                   link: threshold:
### fmx rating ~ Treatment         logit flexible  
### fm1 rating ~ Treatment + Judge logit flexible  

###     no.par    AIC  logLik LR.stat df Pr(>Chisq)
### fmx      5 474.85 -232.42                      
### fm1      6 476.85 -232.42       0  1  

anova(fm1, fmy)

### Likelihood ratio tests of cumulative link models:

###     formula:                   link: threshold:
### fmy rating ~ Judge             logit flexible  
### fm1 rating ~ Treatment + Judge logit flexible  

###     no.par    AIC  logLik LR.stat df Pr(>Chisq)
### fmy      4 476.90 -234.45                      
### fm1      6 476.85 -232.42  4.0507  2     0.1319
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! These results make much more sense, and it is a bit simpler to use than the "manual" comparison of models with `anova`, especially for models with more predictors! It would be nice if `car::Anova` would give an error or a warning of some sort for 'clm' objects...

Comment: If I type `if(!require(RVAideMemoire)){install.packages("RVAideMemoire")}; library(RVAideMemoire); Anova(fm1, type="II")`, I get `Error in Anova(fm1, type = "II") : could not find function "Anova"`! Would you know what is going on?

Comment: You need a `library(car)` before the `library(RVAideMemoire)`.  Let me change that in my answer.

Comment: UPDATE:  a generic `anova` function has been added to the `ordinal` package, so that you can use `anova(model)` directly from the `ordinal` package.  At the time of writing, by default, it reports Wald chi-square tests, whereas `anova(model1, model2)` will report likelihood ratio tests.  `Anova.clm` from `RVAideMemoire` reports LR tests by default.   Also, at the time of writing, `anova(model)` in the `ordinal` package doesn't work with clmm objects.